# How to blacklist IPs on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ip-address, iptables, blacklist

I'm trying to find something similar to iptables in Linux for Windows. I've tried using Windows firewall as well as editing the host file to block specific IPs, but had no success. I've also tried using WIPFW, but it wouldn't even install.. I was able to to use NetLimiter 3 to limit my connection speed to the specific IPs but whenever I setup a filter to block the IPs, those IPs can still connect.

I don't want a hardware firewall or router nor do I want a heavy duty firewall program. Ideally it would be a service that simply lets me add IP addresses and ranges and allows me to block / allow, incoming and/or outgoing connections. A GUI isn't even needed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Netsh AdvFirewall in Windows 7 to issue advanced firewall commands. It's the closest thing you're going to get to iptables that isn't horrific like zone alarm.

[Netsh Advanced Firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that too. It is essentially just a front to Windows Firewall, and for whatever reason, blocking the IPs there does not do anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is here (why or what you're trying to block), but it's beginning to sound like you've got something hooked to your network driver. Like a virus. I mean, you can't even install WIPFW and advanced firewall commands do nothing. It's starting to smell a bit. Might want to do a scan and check things out.

Comment: The error I get with WIPFW is a problem other people have been getting too, it has to do with the drivers not being signed. I have a theory that there are conflicting rules in Windows Firewall which is allowing those IPs through. Definitely no viruses here. I keep my system clean.

Answer (score 0):

[NetLimiter 3 Pro](http://www.netlimiter.com/) will do this just fine, it was just configured poorly. Here is the correct setup:

1. Create a Filter
2. Under "Ip Ranges" put in the desired IPs, leave "Local" unchecked, and make sure "Match All" is checked
3. Leave everything else default, click "Save"
4. Go to the filter in the Node View and add and enable a rule

I think my problem was that I put in too many parameters in the filter and ended up causing it not to function properly.